# Configuring gulp with Angular & system.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, gulp

I have been searching through the web and found various tutorials covering this subject. However, most of the ones i have come across i cannot understand well enough, have been outdated, or do not cover the subject in enough detail.

I am simply trying to set up a gulpfile that will:

1. Compile a Typescript project
2. Copy required modules (Angular)

So that the result is a working Angular app. At this point, i am able to compile TS to JS, however, when i load main.js into index.html, i get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
>       at main.js:1

With the code i have so far, i expected to receive the output of the aMethod function. If i remove "module": "system" from tsconfig, i am able to get the ouput in the node console, however.

I have added angular and its dependencies, together with system.js as npm packages.

### My questions are:

- What am i doing wrong at this point, since i cannot get any output from my transpiled TS app?
- How do i utilize system.js with gulp, to create a task that will copy the @angular modules (core etc.) to my build dir, so my app can make us of Angular?
- What are the advantages, when transpiling, to transpile the various typescript files into a single javascript file?

Thank you in advance. Any help is, as always, much appreciated.

### Project files

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false
    },
    "include": [
        "src/app/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "gulpfile.js",
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const del = require("del");
const ts  = require("gulp-typescript");
const tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");

const appDir = "build/js";

// Tasks

gulp.task("clean", function() {
    del([appDir]);
});

gulp.task("compile", function() {
    return tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .js
        .pipe(gulp.dest(appDir));
});

gulp.task("build", ['clean', 'compile'], function() {
});
```

**main.ts**

```
import { Test } from "./class";

let t1 = new Test();
t1.aMethod("test");
```

**class.ts**

```
export class Test 
{
    aMethod(s: string)
    {
        console.log(s);
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Angular & Python App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
Copy all required dependencies to build directory and then build.
Create your gulp compile like this:

```js
var typeScriptsPath = "src/**/*.ts";
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const tsc = require("gulp-typescript");


/**
 * Compile TypeScript sources and create sourcemaps in build directory.
 */
gulp.task("compile", () => {
  let tsResult = gulp.src(typeScriptsPath)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(tsc(tsProject));
  return tsResult.js
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(".", {
      sourceRoot: '/src'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});


/**
 * copy all dependencies to build directory
 */
gulp.task("libs", () => {
  return gulp.src([
      'core-js/client/shim.min.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.js',
      'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
      'rxjs/**/*.js',
      'rxjs/**/*.js.map',
      'zone.js/dist/*.min.js',
      '@angular/*/bundles/**',
      'jquery/dist/*min.js',
      'lodash/lodash.min.js',
      'bootstrap/dist/js/*min.js',
      'bootstrap/dist/css/*min.css',
      'moment/min/*min.js',
      'underscore/underscore-min*',
      'angular2-cookie/**',
      'moment/**'
    ], {
      cwd: "node_modules/**"
    }) /* Glob required here. */
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/lib"));
});

gulp.task("build", ['compile', 'libs'], () => {
  console.log("Building the project ...");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use systemjs-builder to build main.ts file as same as systemjs file build it. So, your gulp file should be something like this:

```
var Builder = require('systemjs-builder');
var builder = new Builder('', 'systemjs.config.js');

 gulp.task('dist',['compile', 'bundle']);

 gulp.task('compile', shell.task([
     'tsc'
 ]));

 gulp.task('bundle', ['bundle:vendor', 'bundle:app'], function(){
    return gulp.src(['./dist/*.js'], {base:"."})
        .pipe(uglify({
            compress: true,
            mangle: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('bundle:app', function () {
    return builder
        .buildStatic('app/main.js', './dist/main.bundle.js')
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('App bundle error');
            console.log(err);
        });
});

 gulp.task('bundle:vendor', function () {
    return builder
        .buildStatic('app/vendor.js', './dist/vendor.bundle.js')
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Vendor bundle error');
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

where vendor.js file contains all angular vendors libraries like: 'zone', 'reflect' and 'core-js-shim'.

Now you can call gulp dist task to compile all your file.